# Sed command for deleting an inclusive range of characters

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I am working with a xml file that looks a bit like this

```
<w:ins w:id="0" w:author="Nick" w:date="2016-11-23T00:16:00Z"><w:r w:rsidR="009C39E2"><w:rPr><w:ins w:id="1" w:author="Nick" w:date="2016-11-23T00:16:00Z">
```

I am trying to delete everything involving w:date so the product would look like.

```
<w:ins w:id="0" w:author="Nick"><w:r w:rsidR="009C39E2"><w:rPr><w:ins w:id="1" w:author="Nick">
```

Currently, I am trying this incorrect sed command. `sed 's/w:date=".*"//g'` I know this is wrong but I am not sure how I would go about fixing this.

EDIT:

```
cat testing.txt  
<w:ins w:id="0" w:author="Nick" w:date="2016-11-23T00:16:00Z"><w:r w:rsidR="009C39E2"><w:rPr><w:ins w:id="1" w:author="Nick" w:date="2016-11-23T00:16:00Z">

sed 's/ w:date="[^\]*"//g' testing.txt
<w:ins w:id="0" w:author="Nick">
```

Comment: `s/w:date="[^"]*"//g` But, of course, you should not parse HTML, XHTML or XML with regular expressions -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454.

Comment: I am getting an error with your solution. `sed: 1: "s/w:date="[^]*"//g": unbalanced brackets ([])`

Comment: I am unworthy - (Dumb student lol that I am)

Comment: Put it in single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: I was able to get it to run but it did not end up with with the correct result. I will edit my post. EDIT: i have edited my post to add the working regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression is too greedy. You want to match the attribute, a quote, *some non-quote characters* then the ending quote:

```sh
sed 's/ w:date="[^"]*"//g' file
# ..............^^^^
```

```
<w:ins w:id="0" w:author="Nick"><w:r w:rsidR="009C39E2"><w:rPr><w:ins w:id="1" w:author="Nick">
```